Thunderbird 128.6 does not send links to Firefox 133
I have installed Ubuntu 24.10 on a Raspberry pi5.
Seems to work fine, except: Thunderbird 128.6 does not send links to Firefox 133
I have checked settings both in Ubuntu and Thunderbird about standard application. What I find are not editable entries.

Standard applications are managed in the general settings app in Ubuntu. If they are not editable, that may mean that there is a file in your home directory that is not writable by your user.

Thank you. I'll look at it tomorrow. This is a plain vanilla install. This has never happened to me before. I see there has an issue 10+ years ago.
